# Telnet SMTP with expect or shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell, expect, ubuntu-12.04

Want to build up a Auth Smtp Connection with **expect script**... just to test I wanted to get ehlo parameters but expect is not working like this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
set smtp [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
spawn telnet $smtp $port
expect "[2]{2,}[0]{1,}"
send "ehlo\n"
```

I expect the code 220 to come from mailserver to continue to send ehlo ... just like

```
..../...:telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.de 25
Trying 77.238.184.85...
Connected to smtp2-de.mail.vip.ukl.yahoo.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp116.mail.ukl.yahoo.com ESMTP
ehlo
250-smtp116.mail.ukl.yahoo.com
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XYMCOOKIE
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 41697280
250 8BITMIME
```

error saying:

```
spawn telnet smtp.mail.yahoo.de 25
invalid command name "2"
    while executing
"2"
    invoked from within
"expect "[2]{2,}[0]{1,}""
    (file "./login.exp" line 6)
```

if I just write **expect "220"** instead of **expect "[2]{2,}[0]{1,}"** it works but ignors **send "ehlo\n"**

Comment: I suggest using the [smtp](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/smtp.html). You can integrate/use it from expect, you just need to add the line `package require smtp`. If you don't have this package installed, install [tcllib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcllib/) - usually done by installing tcllib with your preferred packet manager)

Comment: If you stick to this approach, you should fix it so you only match the last of a sequence of continued replies. You should ignore any "220-" and only match on "220 " (2, 2, 0, space). By the by, `{1,}` at the end of a regex generally provides no benefit, but here, it's actually wrong, albeit harmless (should not match 2200 etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above adviced I used **exp_internal 1** to get sense of what expects really listen to...
Also I can recommend **autoexpect** which created the expect script not perfectly but after improving some codings it is a real help and at last it worked.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#exp_internal 1
set timeout -1
set smtp [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]
spawn telnet $smtp $port
expect -re {[2]{2,}[0]{1,}}
sleep 3;
send -- "Ehlo\r"
expect -re {[2]{1,}[5]{1,}[0]{1,}}
send -- "quit\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a newline after sending "ehlo":

```
send "ehlo\n"
```

EDIT: Based on your latest edit, you also have to escape the leading bracket in your regex to prevent tcp from trying to interpret it as a command:

```
expect "\[2]{2,}\[0]{1,}"
```

EDIT: Also, your expect line isn't actually matching what you think it is. At this point, I'd suggest running through on of the many tutorials on expect, or simply use [autoexpect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autoexpect) to generate your script.

Comment: thanks... now it works, but stops at 220 smtp109.mail.ukl.yahoo.com ESMTP
... and waits until the webmaiserver quit... the ehlo is not send at all...

Comment: You need to tell expect you're using a regex pattern instead of a glob pattern: `expect -re {[2]{2,}[0]{1,}}`

Comment: To see what expect is/isn't matching, use the command `exp_internal 1` at the beginning of your script. In my experience, autoexpect scripts are handy to give you a starting point, but require lots of editing to handle a more general case.